# Find the constants of the cubic function

Tags: functions

Everyone, I have a cubic function of the form: $Ax + Bx^3$. At $x = 1$, this function corresponds to $y = 0.845$, and at $x = 0$ it corresponds to $y = 0$. How can I determine the constants $A$ and $B$? Thank you for any explanation.

Comment: I request you to accept an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

As Arthur said, you need at least one other data point, as your function is identically zero at $x=0$. To be more specific, you need another point for any $x\neq-1$, since $A(-x) = -Ax$ and $B(-x)^{3} = -Bx^{3}$, so negating $x$ will negate your function no matter what $A,B$ are - your function is what is known as an odd function. So finding $f(-1)$ won't give you any new information.

Once you have that other point, you essentially have two simultaneous equations in $A$ and $B$, which you can then solve.